# How to link to existing boost python module

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I have wondered about this on and off but I never really got a definite answer. Is it possible within the boost.python framework to link against another boost.python module.

For example I have exported class A within boost_python_module(libA) and function B(A a) within boost_python_module(libB). Is it possible to specify in libB to link to A of libA.

The other way of looking at this problem would be that right now I  have to  generate all my bindings in one shot within one module. Is it possible to generate bindings incrementally over several boost_python_module.

Comment: This question is very old, so I'm not sure if boost has fixed something, or the OP has overlooked a little detail, but I didn't observe this behavior with boost version 1.48. When you separately compile two boost::python modules using the same types, you can pass an instance created by one boost python module to a function defined by another boost python module.

Answer (score 1):

The Boost.Python way to handle what you are asking for is to divide your package in compilation units [as explained in the tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/techniques.html#python.reducing_compiling_time) and later do a merge in a main compilation unit that actually declares the modules.

You cannot link independent modules in Boost.Python because they declare specific Python entry points that are executed by Python when you load your module. For example, if the *binary* module name is `mod.so`, the Python interpreter will look for a function called `init_mod` (that is what `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mod)` declares) and execute the code of that function. Within the code of that function, it expects to find Python C-API declarations of objects (instances, classes, etc).

If you link, for example, the `mod.so` binary to another module binary (say, `foo.so`), when Python loads `mod.so`, it would **only** find and execute `init_mod` and will ignore `init_foo`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know well shared library, but what works for me is to import all my modules, which can reference with each others, within python: `import libA; import libB`.

It is of course possible to put these imports in an `__init__.py` file, so that whitin python you just have to do: `import myLib`.

Comment: Hi rafak,
The problem happens because libA and libB and wrappers for c++ code. How can I pass an object create from libA to a function in libB.  
-Sandeep

Comment: If I understand correclty, I have no problem to do what you want. I think that there is some sort of global register for exported types. So I would first import libA (on which libB depends because it uses class A) and then libB. What error (if any) do you get?

Comment: I believe I actually have the same problem - I have multiple different boost::python projects that are interrelated.  A type defined in one doesn't seem to be available in the other, in Python.  I get "No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type" errors.  These go away if I wrap from the same extension module...